# Drifting li items in Foundation

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

I'm new to using Foundation and React. When trying to construct a Nav using the top-bar-right class, I'm experiencing a problem in which my li  items(specifically for "Contractors & Businesses" and "Recreational & MotorCycle"), if they happen to be more than one word, began to drift apart vertically when I reach certain sizes. I tried giving the li items classes, and setting a max height, but this does not work. Picture and code is included. [Pic of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSKbP.jpg)

```
             <nav className="top-bar nav-desktop">
                <div className="wrap">
                  <div className="top-bar-left">
                    <h5 className="site-logo"> 
                     Insurance</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div className="top-bar-right stacked-for-large">
                    <ul className="menu menu-desktop">
                      <li><a  href="#">Bonds</a></li>
                      <li className="Contractors"><a href="#">Contractors & Businesses</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Auto</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Umbrella</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Life</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Recreational & Motorcycle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
```

Comment: Try set style `white-space: nowrap;` for your `<li>` elements.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely worked! However, now I'm experiencing another problem, in which the li items stay on the second line that was created, and begin to disappear off the page. Is there a way to get them to resize and form on a third row? Thanks again.

Comment: What did you mean about the third row? You want to wrap text by `<li>` items?

Comment: Might be easier if you switch to flexbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes